# PySimpleGUI for linux. Debug window appears on top of the main window if last location of closed main window was to the right of debug window

Tags: pysimplegui

I noticed a really particular bug. Maybe it's connected to the issue with a jumping window on linux [here](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5309), idk. I'm on linux too. Basically when i start my script I print some things to the debug window right away with keep_on_top=False and everything goes all right. All the rest prints don't make the debug window to popup suddenly. But I also enabled a feature in PSG to remember the last position of the window. But the debug window always opens at the center(don't know how to change it but would like to)

From here W is window.
Here are the cases when the main W appears at lauch of the script (sg.Window(location) at work).

Case #1: main W about at the center of the screen. Main W is on top of debug W. OK.

Case #2: main W to the left of debug W. Main W is on top of debug W. OK.

Case #3: main W to the right of debug W and covers less or about 20% of debug W. Main W is on top of debug W. OK.

Case #4: main W to the right of debug W and covers more than 20% of it. Not the debug window is on top. **NOT OK**

So we have some vertical line that sits slightly to the right of the screen center that triggers the debug window to pop up.

I could solve this problem just by closing my window on the left side of the screen, but I don't want to do it. It's a small window I like it being on the right side :D

Is there a way to hardcode the debug window to always be behind my windows?

Upd: also if the debug window pops up (case #4) the main windows' icon in the taskbar flashed, inidcating it's out of focus I think

code to replicate:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

debug = sg.Print
debug('debug', keep_on_top=False)

layout = [[sg.Text('window', size=(80,40))]]

window = sg.Window('', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True,
location=sg.user_settings_get_entry('-location-', (None, None)))

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    debug('hi')
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        sg.user_settings_set_entry('-location-', window.current_location())
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: With option `relative_location=(0, 0)` of `sg.Print` to center the debug window. One statement `window.force_focus()` added after window finalized to move focus to main window. It looks everything work fine in my WIN10. I don't have a Linux platform to do the test for your question.

Comment: `window.bring_to_front()` brings this window to the top of all other windows (perhaps may not be brought before a window made to "stay on top").

Comment: Thank you, Jason. bring_to_front seems to fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`window.bring_to_front()` brings this window to the top of all other windows (perhaps may not be brought before a window made to "stay on top")